How to deploy a GitHub WAR project on render.com
I have this reporitory on GitHub. It relies only on JavaEE facilities and two (2) Maven dependencies of my own.
What I need to accomplish is to deploy it on render.com. How can I arrange it?
(My googling did not produce anything relevant. Most of those tutorials/examples/videos are about deploying Spring applications.)

Are you deploying this as a web application? If so, what technologies are you using? Spring Boot? Give me more information and I can help you as I have deployed a Spring Boot application to render.com just recently. Please answer my question by editing your question above instead of answering in the comments so that it will be easier for others to follow when they have a similar question.

This project is based on tomcat embedded project. note that pom.xml seems to couple this project to heroku so deploying on heroku might be a simpler solution.
if using render.com is a requirement, you should probably modify pom.xml. and introduce a Dockerfile, since render.com currently does not support native java apps
